# Control layout of text input and checkboxes within a table cell

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment

I have some HTML that displays a text input and 2 checkboxes side by side.  The HTML is generated by a tool and so I cannot alter the way the HTML is built, I can only apply styling to it using CSS.  My simplified HTML and CSS is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
  td {
    padding: 0;
    }
  fieldset {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
    }
  input[type="text"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
  table.checkboxs  {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
  table.checkboxs td {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <input type="text" id="item1" value="" />
     <fieldset>
      <table summary="" class="checkboxs" border-collapse="">
       <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox_0" name="chkbox" value="1"   /><label for="chkbox_0">One</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox_1" name="chkbox" value="2"   /><label for="chkbox_1">Two</label></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </fieldset>
 </body>
</html>
```

This ends up with the checkboxes displayed higher up than the text item like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

What I would like is them aligned together like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

That seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to achieve it.  If you remove either the text input or the fieldset then the remaining element takes up the minimum vertical space, it is only when they are together that the text input gets pushed down the page.

By all means point out any shortcomings in the HTML, but as I said that is really not under my control, I can only influence the layout using CSS.

Comment: Use `position: relative` along with `top: [some number, can be negative]px` on all textboxes or fieldsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two quick solutions I can think of. The first is to get the table to behave and align more like regular text by setting:

```
table.checkboxs {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisPebble/UyHS5/1/)

Or by aligning the textbox to behave more like the table:

```
input[type="text"] {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisPebble/WhwdD/)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, that worked!  (I just needed to add a !DOCTYPE to my HTML demo file to make it work in IE8)

Answer (score 1):

Try to give float:left to both of them, input and fieldset and then use margin-top if needed to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
input {
 display: inline-block;
}

fieldset {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0
}
```